# Copy-VMGuestFile - Error while trying to copy file from host to VM

Tags: vmware, powercli

I’m trying to use the following command to copy file from host to VM:

```
Copy-VMGuestFile -Source "$TestFilePath" -Destination "$DestinationPath" -LocalToGuest -Force -VM $Machinename -GuestUser "$VMGuestUserID" -GuestPassword "$VMGuestPassword" -ToolsWaitSecs -10 -Verbose
```

The problem is that I’m getting an error:

> WARNING: The guest OS for the virtual machine 'TestVM' is unknown. The
>   operation may fail. Copy-VMGuestFile :  Copy-VMGuestFile  The guest
>   operations agent could not be contacted.

After googling this error, in several posts, there was a recommendation to install VMWare tools. I did. But still copy file command is failing.

Comment: Windows/ Linux? Is the machine powered on? Firewall off? Does the user have access to copy?

Comment: Windows. Machine is powered on. Firewall is off.

Comment: Does the user have access to copy? I think so. How can I check this?

Comment: Check folder permissions. Try adding the user explicitly to the folder. Try turning UAC off as well.

Comment: Now that you have tools what is the latest error message?

Comment: Still, I'm having same error. UAC is off and I have folder permissions.

Comment: When you do $vm = get-vm -name; $vm.extensiondata.guest  what do you get back?